# How to append elements of different class name javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i'm trying to append elements into one set from there class names but getting an error.

```
var temp=document.getElementsByClassName("test");
temp.push(document.getElementsByClassName("we"));
```

Comment: you can't push into temp as it is an object. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: You've tagged the question with `jquery`, but aren't doing the jquery way. 

In jquery, it would be `$('.test', '.we')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`, an array-like object which doesn't have `push` method. You should convert the `NodeList` into an array and then use the `push` method.

```
var temp = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName("test"));

temp.push(...);
```

Alternatively you can use the `querySelectorAll` method:

```
var list = document.querySelectorAll('.test, .we');
```

And if you are loading jQuery:

```
var $collection = $('.test, .we');
```

Comment: is there any or function like and eg.  var temp=document.getElementsByClassName("test test1");.actualy i have two classes one "test test1" and other "x x1" how to combine both nodelist into temp. i'm only able to do for the first one

Comment: Yes, you can use the `querySelectorAll` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're using jQuery. You can do:

```
$('.test, .we')
```

There's also the jQuery [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method which can be used like:

```
$('.test').add('.we')
```

Answer (score 0):

By Using JQuery Yoou can easily get All Elements of Class and then Put These Elements into Another Class.

There is a Code for Solving this Problem :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a= $(".classname1").html();
  $(".classname2").html(a);
});
```

This Code is help you to get All Elements of Classname1 and then You can Put them into Classname2.